# Quiero traer los datos de tres tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Quiero traer las peliculas favoritas de cada usuario incluyendo su comentario, y no encuentro la forma en la cual tendria que plantear la query, intente con la siguiente query pero no me dio resultados

```
SELECT m.title, m.release_date, m.genre, m.imagen, fm.comment FROM movie m, fav_movie fm WHERE m.id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM fav_movie WHERE user_id='3e84ea4d-5081-45ac-a8f1-262cc72313a4')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver mediante *JOINS* de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT user.name,
       movie.title, 
       fav_movie.comment
FROM movie
JOIN fav_movie ON movie.id = fav_movie.movie_id
JOIN user ON user.id = fav_movie.user_id;
```

De esta forma obtendrás:

- Nombres de los users
- Títulos de cada movie
- Comments relacionados

Lo que haces es encontrar las filas que tengan coincidencia entre llave primaria y llave foránea entre las 3 tablas, considerando que en `fav_movie` almacenas dichas claves.